# GWT Hibernate import javax.persistence.*; not resolved why?

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

I'm testing Hibernate but in the beginning I have to fight with some strange errors:

1. my Javax cannot be resolved but why?

I made a build-path to `ebj-peristance.jar`. Copied all files `/libs` of Hibernate in my `WEB-INF/libs` why do I still getting this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737544/gwt-compiler-doesnt-find-javax-libraries

Comment: for which class you are getting error?

Answer (score -1):

i solved it with the help of :

ctrl + shift + T

so powerfull